# Drupal HTTP / HTTPS Persistent Sessions?

Tags: drupal, ssl, https

For some reason my site is not sharing the session between http and https.

My setup,

Drupal 6 with securepages module installed.

You cannsee the example of this here, http://matthewwoodard.com/prducts, if you add to cart you will see the cart empties when it switches to https...any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, are the http pages being cached by drupal/boost?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the following in your settings.php to tell Drupal to allow mixed http and https sessions:

```
$conf['https'] = TRUE;
```